# Extension Rewrites a Model Method to Rewrite a Resource Model Method: How to Extend It?

Tags: extensions, overrides, model, resource-model

I have `ThirdPary_Extension` that rewrites a resource class method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price`. However, `ThirdPary_Extension` goes about doing this a little strange. It's configured to rewrite only `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price`, but in this class' `_construct()`, it's pointing to a resource class that extends off of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price`.

Let me illustrate.

**config.xml**

```
...
<models>
     <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_indexer_price>ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Product_Indexer_Price</product_indexer_price>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</models>
...
```

**ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Product_Indexer_Price**

```
class ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Product_Indexer_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('thirdparty/resource_product_indexer_price');
    }
    ...       
}
```

**ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price**

```
class ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price
{
    protected function _rewrittenMethod()
    {
        // Good stuff
    }
    ...       
}
```

And in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price::reindexAll`, you have `$this->_getResource()->reindexAll()`, which invokes the rewritten method as was intended.

However, this causes some issues. Depending on how you're instantiating the resource model and invoke a method, you may end up with using `ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price` (good) or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price` (bad), among one or two other things. 
Obvisouly, the extension works for re-indexing prices, but I'm not a fan of how it's done. Please correct me if I misunderstand this extension.

**Now the question, how do I rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price` the *right* (lol!) way?**

1. Rewrite both `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price` to re-align everything nicely? Or..
2. Rewrite just `ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price`

Option #1 would typically be my pick, but I'm thinking maybe there was a reason this rewrite was done in such a way, in which case #2 would be the way to go. What say ye?

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite **resource models**.

```
    <models>
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <product_indexer_price>ThirdParty_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price</product_indexer_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
```

### Way to go

I'm always looking to do as less rewrites as possible.
So:

- is there a event fired I can use, use it!
- how can I rewrite with as less impact as possible to avoid module conflicts or problems in future upgrades!

So, I would only rewrite the resource, because that's the less impact I can do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my option #1 would do. I'm just not sure why one would rewrite a resource model method that way. Any idea?

Comment: This is what only option #2 would do I think, because no rewrite on the model is done, only on the resource

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I got slightly confused when you said "You can *also* rewrite..." because it was already mentioned (implied) in the post. Any idea though on my original question? I took approach #1 BTW.

Comment: I'll add some to my answer